# RocksDB Disk Usage

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

When I start my Kafka Streams application many directories and files are created under a temp rocksdb directory.  Can I reduce the amount of disk space consumed by RocksDB?  The total usage seems to be greater than the space needed  by the corresponding Kafka store.  Someone said it could be related to compaction or rolling.  Can I control the compaction or rolling to reduce disk usage?

Comment: Try tuning `write_buffer_size` option of Rocksdb.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in RocksDB configs with `CustomRocksDBConfig` class

https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#rocksdb-config-setter

Comment: with general documentation on rocksdb here: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki and the options best documented here: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/include/rocksdb/options.h and here: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/include/rocksdb/advanced_options.h